# How to early and incrementally deliver to Production on large projects

Tags: testing, release, agile, scrum, continuous-delivery

Many software companies boast that they have quick incremental releases of new functionality into Production. On my back-end project in large company X we have big-releases (1 release in a quarter). We use Scrum with 2-week sprints and system integration testing that is done as a final stage among adjacent teams and clients before releasing to Production (they have their own pack of tests). Our team uses continous integration with nightly regression tests for only our back-end service (our pack of tests respectively). We also use modern agile tools like Jira, git, nexus, stash for code-reviews, spock, junit and teamcity.

We can't afford frequent integration testing among teams as those teams are busy. Our Regression-tests written by QA-devs take up to ~10hours (there are lots of functionality checked against databases with terabutes of data). All our back-end servces are critical in terms of business having hundreds of consumers and work 24/6. In order to go live into Production all our consumers have to run their integration tests too. This requires a lot of coordination and time.We always release on weekends at non-working time.

Thus fast releases are very risky and time-consuming. I would like to hear success stories and how to achieve quick releases? Is this really doable?

Comment: This is a non-sequitur: "fast releases are very risky and time-consuming". I would argue frequent releases reduce risk and are less time consuming. See [Frequency reduces difficulty](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FrequencyReducesDifficulty.html)

Comment: How do you make sure then that your changes don't have bugs if you don't have much time for testing? You would have to run full regression pack in multiple cases which is time-consuming. Not running them is risky.

Comment: If your releases are more frequent, they are smaller, which means less testing. Complexity increases exponentially with the size of your release - which means testing is much harder. If you're deploying a spaghetti code monolith - stick with your big releases.

Comment: The thing is that such an approach doesn't work in many companies. It's all about risks of triggering new bugs in other parts of a system. That's why it's called a regression pack. On top of this It's not always clear what tests to run. e.g. when you do a new commit all Junit-tests get run automatically in CI - you don't do it partly right?

Comment: "The thing is that such an approach doesn't work in many companies." Citation needed.

Comment: Corrected --> "The thing is that such an approach doesn't work in many companies due to lack of knowledge how to do it."

Comment: [My answer to a somewhat different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23848450/634576) mentions tactics that are also relevant here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize my comments. It is a non-sequitur to say that, "fast [frequent] releases are very risky and time-consuming".

Doing smaller releases reduces the difficulty of testing those releases. If you are more frequently releasing, the size of your release will decrease, the number of features changed will be smaller.

See: [Martin Fowler's FrequencyReducesDifficulty](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FrequencyReducesDifficulty.html)

To an extent the risk of small release vs big release depends on the architecture of your system. If you've got a tangled monolith then the risk of a change effecting an unrelated component is high. To solve this you need to break components up so they're more isolated from each other.

If your architecture is loosely coupled, then there are fewer connections between components. Each component should therefore be easier to test in isolation. A release can become only for certain components - you don't need to deploy everything, every time.

You can also engineer to make releases easier. For example, if you have a highly-available system, you could run the old and new at the same time, then shut down the old version and allow a fail-over to occur.

You don't have to release everything in one big bang. You can incrementally roll things out, whether that be by region or specific set of users.

APIs should have a contract. That is more than just functions; wire formats and behaviours. As long as you know that all services honour that contract then they should work. Good automated tests should help. Again, consider breaking large APIs into smaller ones.

To say that, "The thing is that such an approach doesn't work in many companies" is also dubious. The biggest obstacle I've seen is a cultural one; people don't want to change and the process is entrenched.

To do frequent releases you don't have to solve all problems. You can start off just doing it for new features and services. It's never going to happen if you dont just start.

Comment: Dave.Thanks for clarification and link. You are right in terms of monolithic systems - this is one of the major issues. There are many more issues. Fo example 1. If an external cliemt-API gets changed for backend-consumers then all consumers should be tested against new functionality and subsequently released which requires coordination and time. 2. 24/6 systems can be released only on a particular day.

Comment: Answering my last 2 questions: These issues can be resolved mostly with [micro-services](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) and [service loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_loose_coupling_principle)

Comment: Agree, I see microservices as a variant of SOA. Loose coupling is best practice in SOA.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301849/7028): you reason in terms of cost of a delivery, but that is a bit misleading.

What matters in reality is the cost of a "failed" delivery: since delivering is complex/lengthy/convoluted of course you want to do so as little as possible (and fail as little as possible). That is one possible approach. In order to do that you want to minimize the number of bugs, because releasing a patch becomes lengthy and expensive.

The other possible approach is to make it easier to deploy so you can do it more often. Once deployment is one-click away, then you realize that *the cost of failing* becomes low. The reason for this is that is the cost of a bug is low -- you can fix and click-deploy away. This in turn (normally) allows you to reduce the amount of testing before shipping.

Amazingly, based on personal experience, you might end up noticing that most bugs are caught early anyways because of the added benefit of focus -- develop and ship straight away. Also, there is another category of *defects* which are not normally even considered that much in big-bang systems: bugs in the specs. In other words, if you build the wrong thing, this is normally very expensive -- not so with continuous delivery: cheap to ship means cheap to change.

Comment: +1 also, if its quick and cheap to deploy - it is also quick and cheap to roll back if it is really mission critical.

Answer (score 0):

- Automate

  - Your teams shouldn't have extra work because of regression tests.
  - same for production and your customers
  - no / not much coordination for the tests should be needed

    - setup the test infrastructure automatically too
- Faster and earlier feedback

  - make the integration and regression tests faster, find out what takes longest now
  - run them more often, e.g. by adding more buildagents

Your end goal might be weekly releases but start with montly ones first.
And the regressions tests every hour.